# Brazilian Girlfriends Visa refused - Administrative Review

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, brazil

MY girlfriend was recently refused her tier 5 charity visa. We are looking at lodging an appeal to see if we can change the decision. Here is the reasons for refusal. It is a conversation between two of her employers who work at the company she would have been working with for a year :

** (My girlfriend) called G. last night and basically she was refused for 2 reasons....
·        Not enough points on the point based system by the home office- basically the embassy looks at the job she is coming to do and they have said she is not eligible.  Remember- the description of what she is doing this time- was different as before for her.  I have applied for a certificate of sponsorships for a charity visa using the description of volunteer instructor duties (same as my girlfriend) before, for another international- not Brazilian, and no issues.  So it appears that the Brazilian Embassy simply does not like this.  This will put me off now for any future Brazilian Trainees- as this has proven it does not work- unfortunately.

·        The other reason she gave (on another email) that the certificate of sponsorship number for embassy  which I issued to her has expired- that is because she took too long to apply for it.  According to G.- she was working to earn the money to apply to pay for the fees for her application.

I confirm that we are not in a position to re-apply  for another certificate of sponsorship for (my girlfriend)- as extremely risky- as highly likely it will not work again, plus the fees she will have to pay again and the time it will take- is simply not worth it.**

I am looking at the form for the administrative appeal and it says that she would have to write down why she thinks the officer who did the form made a mistake.

where do we go from here? can anyone please please give us some advice, and how we can go about this?

I was thinking of saying that she wasn't aware that the number given to her sponsor would expire, and that it would have been valid, had she known prior to it expiring. also she could say that other brazillians have been accepted for this role.

again, any help you can give us would be greatly appreciated!

Andrew.

Comment: Visa for what country?

I'd suggest though that if the original reasons given for entering the country are no longer accurate, then an appeal seems unlikley to suceed. The term "administrative appeal" implies you are appealing on the grounds that the government got some form of process wrong. Have they? If not, probably a wate of time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about Tier 5 in the UK Points Based System that require an employer or economic  sponsor or government authorized exchange and where the visas are typically issued for longer than 6 months are suitable for the Expats site http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions